# What is the name of the writing that appears on the screen when watching television?

Tags: meaning, words, katakana

When watching the news and other shows on television, I often see various written content displayed on the screen for brief periods of time, usually on the bottom, but sometimes on the right. I just learned that in English it is called closed captioning. I saw the term on Jisho, before posting. It is used frequently on news programs on a daily basis. Is there a Japanese term for this word? What is this content called?

Comment: Like closed captioning? https://jisho.org/word/51868dc0d5dda7b2c6006878

Comment: what, headlines? captions? closed captioning?? what are you talking about? any specific shows or examples?

Comment: [字幕]{じ・まく}?????

Comment: @JACK I'm really impressed by your inquisitiveness. I have tried to garner stackexchange points by submitting answers, and have about the same points as you, but have only reached 10K people, where your questions have benefited six times that many...   I learn a lot from your questions. Thanks.

Comment: I learn from you and everybody else here. Good stuff.

Comment: In the US, "closed captions" are a data stream separate from any text displayed in the video itself. It is switchable on/off and contains a text transcription of any speech or sound effects, and is intended to assist the deaf or hard of hearing. This should be the same as 字幕 in Japan.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**テロップ** (from English [*telop*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telop)) is the generic word for any type of superimposed text on TV, and it's understood by everyone. You can see many テロップ's in the image below, at the top, right, left and bottom of the screen.

[image]

**字幕** ("subtitle") is another common word, but it basically only refers to a transcription or translation of what the person on screen is saying.

Comment: That must be British English...

Comment: @istrasci I agree, It looks like what Americans refer to as a teleprompter.

Comment: A very useful explanation, a teleprompter.

Comment: Oh, is "telop" understood by BrE speakers? I didn't know that :)

Comment: @naruto I can't say with complete confidence that it is typically used by Brittish English, but it would seem possible.  The big issue is that it seems that the telop died out in the 50's/60's, so it might just be a dead word.  I definitely haven't heard of it before.

Comment: a teleprompter is literally a screen which prompts the announcer about what to say next, it has nothing to do with showing the audience any information.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telop

Comment: Very interesting comments.

Comment: lots of things that "died out" in western culture still exist in Japanese culture. :P  Fax machines, for example. :P

Comment: @ericfromabeno But [ticker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticker_tape) is much older than telop and is still in use in English-speaking countries :)

Comment: @naruto As a native British person I can say with confidence that no one would have a clue what you were talking about if you said "telop". We just call them subtitles. We also don't call it 'closed captioning', though I expect many people would understand this phrase at least.