# What are the illustrations used in Japanese TV called?

Tags: words

What are the illustrations they use to show information in Japanese TV called?  I don't know if I'm describing them well, so I've included a picture.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to this physical board itself? Then there is no well-known specific name for this type of board. It's probably just called ボード or 情報ボード. Handheld smaller boards (roughly the same size as sketchbooks) are commonly called フリップ. See [these image search results](https://search.yahoo.co.jp/image/search?ei=UTF-8&fr=sfp_as&aq=-1&oq=&ts=796&p=%E3%83%95%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%80%80%E3%83%90%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A8%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3&meta=vc%3D). Text digitally superimposed on screen is called [テロップ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/60185/5010).

Or are are you referring to the names of these specific illustrations? I'm at least seeing a 人物の写真, a 人物関係図 and 会話の再現イラスト, but the catch-all term for these illustrations is perhaps just 情報 ("information").

Comment: Maybe he means the style of board where you see them peeling off panels to reveal information underneath.

Comment: @kandyman That style has a slangy name [もんたメソッド](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/keyword/%a4%e2%a4%f3%a4%bf%a5%e1%a5%bd%a5%c3%a5%c9), but this board seems to have nothing to be peeled.

Comment: The Monta Method - wow, never heard of that before. 面白いね。

Comment: Was it popularized by みのもんたさん or something?

Comment: Yes, this "peeling the フリップ" method is inspired by みのもんた. See [this video](https://youtu.be/co4oGsWu5XQ?t=102).